# join tables and loops

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have joined tables of posts and tags like this:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('posts');
$this->db->join('posts_tags', 'posts.post_id = posts_tags.post_id', 'left');
$this->db->join('tags', 'posts_tags.tag_id = tags.tag_id', 'left');
```

How do i loop through each post, and display a list of their respective tags. 
For example:

```
post1: tag1, tag2
post2, tag1, tag3
```

At the moment, i can display the tags, but it return two rows for post 1 and two. The output now is:

```
post1: tag1
post1: tag2
post2: tag1
post2: tag3
```

How do i return one row for post, with all the related tags inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use group concat and group results

```
$this->db->select('posts.*');
$this->db->select('GROUP_CONCAT(posts_tags.tag_title) as TagTitles');
$this->db->from('posts');
$this->db->join('posts_tags', 'posts.post_id = posts_tags.post_id', 'left');
$this->db->join('tags', 'posts_tags.tag_id = tags.tag_id', 'left');
$this->db->group_by('posts.id');
$this->db->get();
```